# TotalValidatorPro issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, wcag

I am trying to get [TotalValidatorPro](http://www.totalvalidator.com/help/help.html) to crawl a page that requires a login. Even if I put the login information in the authtification tab. It wont go passed the login page. Even if Im already logged in and I try to start the validator from the logged in landing page. Has anyone used this tool to validate there webpages? Do you know the solution to this issue?

Trying to go through the entire web app to bring it up at WCAG 2.0 A standards.

If you have any solution or opinions on this matter I would greatly appreciate it!.

Thanks!